# How to solve recursion relations analytically in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For example, I have the following recursion and I want to get f[3,n]:

```
f[m_, n_] := Module[{}, If[m < 0, Return[0];];
  If[m == 0, Return[1];];
  If[2*m - 1 >= n, Return[0];];
  If[2*m == n, Return[2];];
  If[m == 1, Return[n];];
  Return[f[m, n - 1] + f[m - 1, n - 2]];]
f[3, n]
```

The code does not seem to work. Please help. Many thanks!

Comment: Could you describe what, exactly, "does not seem to work?"

Comment: There's no reason to expect this code to give analytic / symbolic answers. The command you want for symbolic stuff is `RSolve[]`, but it's not very good at multivariable recursion relations.

Comment: @Simon "It's not very good" is rather polite in this case :D

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite recursion because when `m` is not initialized, none of the boundary cases match.

Instead of using `Return` you'll get more predictable behavior if you use functional programming, ie

```
f[m_, n_] := Which[
  m < 0, 0,
  2 m - 1 >= n, 0,
  2 m == n, 2,
  m == 1, n,
  True, f[m, n - 1] + f[m - 1, n - 2]
  ]
```

In this case `Which` can not decide which option to take with `n` not initialized, so `f[3, n]` will return an expression.

One way to get a formula is with `RSolve`. Doesn't look like it can solve this equation in full generality, but you can try it with one variable fixed using something like this

```
Block[{m = 3},
 RSolve[f[m, n] == f[m, n - 1] + f[m - 1, n - 2], f[m, n], {n}]
 ]
```

In the result you will see `K[1]` which is an arbitrary iteration variable and `C[1]` which is a free constant. It's there because boundary case is not specified

Comment: Sorry, the recursion I gave is self-contradictory. If I have the following instead:

Comment: It seems there is a typo in "with m not initialized" (/.m->n)?